# Does English slang have a feminine version of "breaking someone's balls"?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, slang, offensive-language

A question out of curiosity. Probably ***Not Safe For Work***.

Often times, I come across this phrase especially in Hollywood movies and sitcoms. Depending on how it's used, it either means that "someone is just messing around/ kidding" with the other person or "someone wants all the nagging/botheration" to stop.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_someone%27s_balls) categorizes it as a vulgar slang with the following definitions:

> 1. to seriously irritate or nag someone.
> 2. to tease or ridicule someone; to take the piss out of someone.

An example would be the following conversation from the movie [GoodFellas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/), between 2 men.

> ***Tommy DeVito***: No more shines, Billy.
>
> ***Billy Batts***: What?
>
> ***Tommy DeVito***: I said, no more shines. Maybe you didn't hear about it, you've been away a long time. They didn't go up there and tell you. I don't shine shoes anymore.
>
> ***Billy Batts***: Relax, will ya? Ya flip right out, what's got into you? ***I'm breaking your balls a little bit, that's all. I'm only kidding with ya...***
>
> ***Tommy DeVito***: Sometimes you don't sound like you're kidding, you know, there's a lotta people around...

<sup>Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/quotes?item=qt0434774)</sup>

Suppose, the conversation was happening between two women or it involved a woman in the picture, what slang would used in place of "breaking (someone's) balls"?

I feel there might be some colloquialisms/slang that Native speakers would be using. As a non-native speaker, I am intrigued to know what that phrase might be.

Comment: If you wanted a direct opposite, you coooould but probably wouldn't want to say "I'm punting your c***." (I have no problem with the word but I don't want to offend anyone more sensitive than I by writing it out).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Now stop [*getting on my tits*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=getting+on+my+tits). From Urban Dictionary,

> To be really annoyed by someone or something and to express it in a funny exclamation

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of a sufficient gender-correct alternative, I've actually heard women use "busting my balls" for themselves, though one's gotta be a pretty tough chick to pull that off.

Comment: It's an equal opportunity expression.

Answer (score 1):

*Busting [someone's] chops* is entirely neutral as is *getting your goat*, and depending on the scenario you might say *he's on my ass* about this or that...

*Busting someone's balls* generally, where I live, is more about getting on to someone about something - sometimes just to get a rise out of them, often to take them to task over an issue.  *Busting chops* is generally more to get a rise as is *getting someone's goat*.  So more commonly here, like if you have a harsh boss that is demanding, you'd say he/she is on your ass all the time.  I don't hear ball busting very often at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a feminine version, but a somewhat neutral one for definition #2 is *roasting*. From [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Roast):

> To humorously mock or humiliate someone with a well-timed joke, diss or comeback.

I've heard it mostly in the context of, ex, teasing one or both members of the couple during wedding speeches.

Answer (score 0):

*breaking my female balls*

Used by the title character on the popular TV comedy *VEEP*, Season 1, starring Julia Louis-Dreyfus. Recognizing that females don't have testicles, this is a transferred usage of an anyway usually metaphorical usage when applied to males.